# Error happening while using json_tuple syntax in hive script

Tags: json, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I have updated the hive version from 0.20 to 0.13.1.

I'm using the following table and queries to extract the json from S3.

**Table:**

```
    > CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE in_app_logs (
    > event string,
    > app_id string,
    > idfa string,
    > idfv string
    > )ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    > LOCATION 's3://test/in_app_logs/ds=2015-04-20/';
```

My Query Looks likes the below for Version 0.20 and it's working fine with the old version.

```
    SELECT
       get_json_object(in_app_logs.event, '$.ev') as event_type,
       get_json_object(in_app_logs.event, '$.global.app_id') as app_id,
       get_json_object(in_app_logs.event, '$.global.ios.idfa') as idfa,
       get_json_object(in_app_logs.event, '$.global.ios.idfv') as idfv
    FROM in_app_logs;
```

In the new version it's changed to [json_tuple](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-json_tuple). I have tried this query in updated version. **Got Error.**

```
SELECT b.event_type, c.app_id, d.idfa, d.idfv
FROM in_app_logs a
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(a.event, 'ev') b as event_type,
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(a.event.global, 'app_id') c as app_id,
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(a.event.global.ios, 'idfa', 'idfv') d as idfa, idfv
```

**S3 Logs:**

```
   {
      "installed_at": "2015-04-17T12:10:24Z",
      "ev": "event_install",
      "global": {
        "ios": {
          "idfv": "887DF776-C1FC-4567-DESF-741AC72197D1",
          "time_zone": "EDT",
          "model": "iPhone7,2",
          "screen_size": "320x568",
          "carrier": "AT&T",
          "language": "en",
          "idfa": "CD04291C-0D80-4377-6CS9-B46089A05F15",
          "os_version": "8.2.0",
          "country": "US"
        }
```

Can anyone help me to extract the json data?

Comment: Do you have sample output from old version. Can you share the error/log you are getting? What is file format, Is it .json file.

Comment: What error? Pls add to post.

Answer (score 1):

The '.' operator is only supported for structs or list of structs.
You are trying to apply that on a STRING type.

You probably need something like this:

```
SELECT x.event_type, x.app_id, x.idfa, x.idfv
FROM in_app_logs a
LATERAL VIEW JSON_TUPLE(
    a.event,
   'ev',
   'global.app_id',
   'global.ios.idfa',
   'global.ios.idfv'
) x AS event_type, app_id, idfa, idfv
```